# NLP , Specific Text Extraction

Tags: nlp

I have to train a model which can identify the country from a random text. I have the country list.

Now I am struggling to find a solution that can train the model on the country list and when I provide a random text to that model as an input, it identifies the country name as an output.

eg:-

"I live in India" will give "India"
"London is the capital of United Kingdom" will give "United Kingdom"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. I can't understand what your question is, can you add some details and make it more clear?

Comment: Please, edit the original post, do not add info here in the comments because some user could miss them. You have to click the "edit" button below the original text.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.